# How to bind knockout viewmodel to dynamically load page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I load page dynamically with jquery.load function and but loaded page not bind to viewModel?

app.js

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observable();

    Sammy(function() {
        this.get("#/users",function() {
            $.get("/api/users",function(data){
                self.users(data);
            });
            $("#content").load("pages/users.html");
        });
    }).run("#/");
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script src="statics/js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="statics/js/lib/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="statics/js/lib/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
        <script src="statics/js/lib/sammy.js"></script>
        <script src="statics/js/lib/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

pages/users.html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: users">
    <li><span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's because the JavaScript in your current page has run prior to loading the new content so the new content is not aware of the jQuery/JavaScript code. For jQuery have a look at the on() method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JayBlanchard how jquery on() can help me?

Comment: You need to go read the docs - it may not help you but it may point you in the right direction. If not you can start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=binding+javascript+to+dynamically+added+content

Comment: Doesn't the jQuery load function include a callback?  Why not load the div html first and then set the KO bindings in the callback function?  That way, you'll ensure that the html has been loaded first.

Comment: Look at the very last example here... http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved my problem re-apply binding after after dynamic page loading

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observable();

    Sammy(function() {
        this.get("#/users",function() {
            $.get("/api/users",function(data){
                self.users(data);
            });
            $("#content").load("pages/users.html", null, function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status != "error") {
                } 
                    ko.applyBindings(self, $(".dynamic-page-content").get(0)); 
                }
            });
        });
    }).run("#/");
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: -1 This should NOT be the accepted answer, applybindings is not designed to be used like this and it will not work properly in all cases. Unless you want to test your awesome skills at tracking down some of the most obscure and difficult to find bugs, in which case go ahead and try this... and enjoy the resulting debugging challenges.

Comment: -1 At the time of this answer the act of applying bindings more than once to an element (or elements) might not have thrown an error, but it does today and I'm thinking the developers on the knockout team know how they want you to bind to dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 11):

```
$("#content").load("/pages/users.html", function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
}
```

should do it...